# How to handle user timezones preference with Django PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, django, database-design, django-models, django-timezone

I am new to Django timezones. I need my users to select their timezone from a list so I can store it in PostgreSQL database. My questions are:

- What is the best way to generate a list of timezones for the user to
  select from?
- What is the best data structure to store the selected
  timezone to the database?